# OpenResty disable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 in auto genereated certs

Tags: ssl, lua, openresty

Lately i was playing with **openresty** and **lua-resty-auto-ssl** and can't find how to **disable** TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1, (and add ciphers). I just read whole internet twice, and found nothing. In nginx is simple one line `ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;` but its not affecting lua-resty-auto-ssl i have no idea how to do it, would be nice if someone could shed some light on this topic.

Comment: 'Auto generated certs' have nothing to do with it. The TLS protocol version is determined by the applications, not by the certificates. Off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found answer [here](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#lua_ssl_protocols):

`lua_ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;`

Comment: This didn't work for me. It doesn't limit the SSL version. Are you able to provide a gist of your nginx.conf?

Comment: https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#lua_ssl_protocols i found answer here. The values are not for limit (blacklist) ssl but are like whitelist, so in this answer only TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3 are allowed.

Comment: You can test your openresty configuration here https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest and be sure you using openresty not nginx.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenResty on bionic using the docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/openresty/openresty)  with the [auto-ssl lua component](https://github.com/auto-ssl/lua-resty-auto-ssl) on our production system required that we simply use the standard directive `ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;` inside the `http` section. This is currently working for us as shown here:

```
➜  http --ssl=tls1.1 https://my-custom-domain.foo.com/my-special-page --output tmp.html

http: error: SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my-custom-domain.foo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /my-special-page  (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:1122)'))) ...
```

I hope this can be clarifying for some people as using the `lua_ssl_protocols` directive didn't work for me.